# How make filter for search in object?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Please help fix the script.

I have follow data structure in $scope.peoples

I need find follow object: '{name: 'dima', age: '4'}' and put it in $scope.filteredPeoples. I need use filter.

My filter version:

```
app.controller('mainController', ['$scope', 'namesFilter', function($scope, namesFilter) {
      $scope.peoples = [
        {name: 'anton', age: '1'},
        {name: 'serg', age: '2'},
        {name: 'sveta', age: '3'},
        {name: 'dima', age: '4'},
        {name: 'stas', age: '5'},
        {name: 'pavel', age: '6'}
      ];
      $scope.filteredPeoples = namesFilter($scope.peoples, {name: 'dima'});
}]).filter('names',function() {
      return function(array) {
                var result = [];

        array.forEach(function(item, i, arr) {
          if(item.color == 'dima') {
            result.push(item);
          };
        });   

        return result;
      };
    });
```

But it filter does not worked. Console is not displays error messages, but filteredPeoples is empty array.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/zlodiak/p3qye20f/17/)

Comment: `item.color == 'dima'` should be `item.name == 'dima'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check on the proper object property :

```
if(item.name== 'dima') { //not item.color
            result.push(item);
          };
```

Here's your [updated working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p3qye20f/19/)